# Find to list files for not matching given string

Tags: files, find

I am searching all `*.out` files from a specific directory and trying to list all the file names where the given string is not present in those files or not matching by executing the below-listed command.

```
find . -type f -name "*.out" -exec grep -L "226 Transfer complete." {} \;
```

Unfortunately, it is not listing the files which do not have the string `226 Transfer complete`, instead it displayed the series of string `226 Transfer complete`.

@don_crissti, as per your solution

```
find . -type f ! -exec grep -q 'PATTERN' {} \; -print
```

the 'PATTERN' present twice anywhere in my test files. If one of the locations having the 'PATTERN' and other does not have, then it is not listing the file (In my case, it should list). can I use count to validate it? Like if I get the count less than 2, then it should list the files which are considered to be erroneous.

Comment: Not really sure, but try `-v` option in `grep` instead of `-L`.

Comment: Are you *sure* the string "226 Transfer complete." is correct?  Is there *really* supposed to be a `.` (period) there?  And remember `.` match *one character of anything* in `grep` - while `\.` matches an actual `.`...  Do you need it all?  Wouldn't the numeric-code be enough?  Eg.  "^226 Transf" - beginning of line starts with 226 Transf - may be enough... or maybe "^226 Trans.*comp"...  Also try `[Tt]` and `[Cc]` to match both upper-and lower-case.

Comment: @BaardKopperud I was thinking that too, but it doesn't explain why he got that string on the terminal, unless he's using a `grep` that doesn't understand `-L`...

Comment: What system are you on and does `grep --version` output anything?

Comment: I mean as @Thomas wrote, the alternative is using `-v` -- perhaps combined with `-l`...  `-l` prints names of files with at least one match, `-v` reverse the pattern... but together - looking at the description of the `man`-page - that *should* be exactly what `-L` (which you're already using!) should do.

Comment: Hm....interesting. It seems to work with a pipe `find . -type f -name "*.out" | grep -v "226 Transfer complete."`, but not within the `find...-exec...` call.

Comment: @Thomas That `grep` will grep all filenames not matching the pattern... Not really what this is about.

Comment: Sorry guys, completely didn't get the question right.

Comment: +1 exactly - negate the `-exec` rather than the `grep`

Comment: @thomas, I tried -v and it dint work as expected. its printing the actual content of each files matching the condition.@ Baard Kopperud,

Comment: @BaardKopperud , i am looking for files with not  successful transfer. yeah. we can use '226'. I used dot to search the files by refering in the current directory.

Comment: @Kusalananda and don_Crissti, when i tried "grep --version", its not working. But don, it works as per your solution. thanks. let me try testing the actual changes and let you know. I appreciate all of your time and help.

Comment: Sorry @don_crissti. Its not working as expected. -L wont work.. My bad. Is there any option to list the files which not matching the string pattern.

Comment: @don_crissti, the 'PATTERN' present twice anywhere in my test files. If one of the locations having the 'PATTERN' and other does not have, then it is not listing the file (In my case, it should list). can I use count to validate it? Like if I get the count less than 2, then it should list the files which are considered to be erroneous.

Comment: @don_crissti: In my example, I am searching for the pattern "226 transfer completed" in the files present in \home\log\. directory. Pattern "226 transfer completed" present at the top and the bottom portion of the test file. There are some cases, the top portion will be holding the string "226 transfer completed" and the bottom portion hold different. As a result, it is considered as erroneous file and filename should get printed so if I execute this command, its not listed as I understand this command is checking for the PATTERN only once in the entire file.

Comment: @balayuva - didn't you know that _before_ posting the question here ? Please ask a separate question and explain exactly what you are trying to accomplish... but try to make an effort and make up your mind _before_ posting the question.